# Sd card not appearing on Linux steam

Tags: sd-card

I was using the Linux version of steam on my Chromebook OS but I didn't have enough space available on my local drive to download the game,I had a SD card inserted though but to my dismay I was unable to find my SD card when I tried to add it as one of my main download locations for steam.